# Car, gas, crow problem - looking for analytic solution

Tags: probability, puzzle

I made up this problem recently.

> [possible configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhEfh.png)
>
> Imagine you are lost in a car on a long circular road in a hot desert.
> You have enough gas to go halfway around the circle. There is a gas
> station that is your only hope for survival, but you don’t even know
> where you are, let alone which direction will get you to the gas.
>
> With this much information, your best option is to pick a direction
> and go that way until you reach the gas or run out. Your chances of
> survival are 50%.
>
> Now imagine there is also a dead crow on the side of the road. All
> three objects are randomly distributed around the circle with all
> locations equally likely. Also, you are told which direction will get
> you to the crow before the gas station. Does this help? What should
> you do? What are your chances?

I have the sketch of a solution, but it leans on a simulation. Is there a purely analytic solution?

> The gas station and the car divide the road into two segments, and you
>  need the smaller segment to survive. The randomly placed crow is more
>  likely to be in the larger segment, simply because it’s larger. You
>  should go in the other direction.
>
>  [coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfw4v.png)
>
>  To avoid considering cases
>  separately, we define a coordinate system going from the car opposite
>  the crow-first direction with circle circumference 1, so g < c. We
>  know that 0 ≤ g < 1 but the probability of g → 1 is vanishingly small
>  since it would also require that c → 1. It is reasonable to assume
>  (and simulation confirms) that the probability density function for g
>  is linear so it must be
>
>  [probability density function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boJ4Q.png)
>
>  The probability of survival is the sum of
>  the areas shown, p(g<1/2) = 3/4.

Comment: See also [this Puzzling SE post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112422/the-loop-of-rope-dilemma).

Answer (score 4):

I agree that if you know the direction in which the crow appears before the gas station, then going the opposite direction increases your chances of survival from $1/2$ to $3/4$.

First let's reformulate your problem statement. Suppose your current position is $0$, and use angular displacement from your car to mark points on the road. Then the position of the gas station $X$ and the crow $Y$ are uniformly distributed over $[0,2\pi)$.

If $X<Y$, then with our strategy, we survive iff $X\leq\pi$. We can use Bayes' theorem to compute the survival probability in this case:
$$\mathbb P(X\leq\pi\mid X<Y)=\frac{\mathbb P(X<Y\mid X\leq\pi)\cdot\mathbb P(X\leq\pi)}{\mathbb P(X<Y)}=\mathbb P(X<Y\mid X\leq\pi),$$
since $\mathbb P(X\leq\pi)=\mathbb P(X<Y)=1/2$. But we can break down the last probability by conditioning on the value of $Y$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X<Y\mid X\leq\pi)&=\mathbb P(X<Y\mid X\leq\pi, Y\leq\pi)\cdot\mathbb P(Y\leq\pi)\\
&\qquad+\mathbb P(X<Y\mid X\leq\pi, Y>\pi)\cdot\mathbb P(Y>\pi)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{3}{4}.
\end{align*}
So when $X<Y$ our probability of survival is $3/4$. By an analagous argument, when $X>Y$ our probability of survival is $3/4$, so our new strategy gives us a $3/4$ chance to survive, as you claimed.